# i Want to toggle "YES" Access management for Azure resources using microsoft graph commands

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Browse to Azure Active Directory > Properties > Access management for Azure resources
Select Yes under Access management for Azure resources, and Save

Help me in sorting this script and to toggle yes
I have Global Admin rights at tenant level

### script i have written:-

## Connect to Microsoft Graph API

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.AccessAsUser.All"

## Get the directory setting object

$directorySetting = Get-MgDirectorySetting -Filter "DisplayName eq 'Access management for Azure resources'" -Property Values

## Update the directory setting object to set the property to "Yes"

$directorySetting.Values.EnableAadResourceAccessPolicy = $true

## Update the directory setting with the modified object

Set-MgDirectorySetting -Id $directorySetting.Id -Values $directorySetting.Values

### ERROR :-

Welcome To Microsoft Graph!
Get-MgDirectorySetting : The term '**Get-MgDirectorySetting**' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:5 char:21

- $directorySetting = Get-MgDirectorySetting -Filter "DisplayName eq 'A ...
- ```
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-MgDirectorySetting:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

The property '**EnableAadResourceAccessPolicy**' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:8 char:1

- $directorySetting.Values.EnableAadResourceAccessPolicy = $true
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFound
  ```

Set-MgDirectorySetting : The term 'Set-MgDirectorySetting' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:11 char:1

- Set-MgDirectorySetting -Id $directorySetting.Id -Values $directorySet ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-MgDirectorySetting:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

I was expecting to Toggle to YES
Browse to Azure Active Directory > Properties > Access management for Azure resources
Select Yes under Access management for Azure resources, and Save

using powershell with Microsoft.graph commands

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/get-mgdirectorysetting?view=graph-powershell-beta) `Get-MgDirectorySetting` is available for Microsoft Graph PowerShell beta.

You need to change the profile by using the `Select-MgProfile` command

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "Directory.AccessAsUser.All"
Select-MgProfile -Name "beta"
...
```

Instead of `Set-MgDirectorySetting` I would use [Update-MgDirectorySetting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.identity.directorymanagement/update-mgdirectorysetting?view=graph-powershell-beta)

```
...
Update-MgDirectorySetting -Id $directorySetting.Id -Values $directorySetting.Values
...
```